# Sampling with replacement using python

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
X, y = load_data(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,
                                                test_size=0.3, random_state=123,
                                            shuffle=True)
def sample(X,y):
# code attempt
 train_index = sorted(np.random.permutation(len(X)))
 test_index = [i for i in range(0,len(X)) if i not in train_index]
for i in range(0,len(X)):
# train, validation set split
    x_trn, x_val = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_trn, y_val = y[train_inex], y[test_index]

return x_trn , x_val, y_trn, y_val
```

then call it as

```
sample(X_train, y_train)
```

Fill in the code  to uniformly draw samples with replacement from the training data. The size of the sampled dataset should be equal to the training dataset size.

Comment: This looks like homework.  You need to make a good faith attempt to solve this yourself before coming to us for help.

Comment: i did try but my sample keep giving same result of the data set:

Comment: You aren't supposed to be using the test data at all here.  You're just supposed to pick N random samples from the training data, where N = the size of the training data.

Comment: Please stick to a relevant & descriptive title, without clutter (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what the assignment says, this is all you need.  You pick indicies at random, then return the points at those indices.

```
def sample(X,y):
    picks = np.random.randint(0,len(X),len(X))
    return X[picks], y[picks]
```